# OSX Yosemite network-popdown suddenly have a permanent Device entry

Tags: macos, mac

After the latest minor Mac OS-X upgrade to Yosemite, I discovered I suddenly have a new and permanent entry in my network-popdown menu, located under a "Device" heading named SETUP.

[image: network-popdown menu]

It's permanent in the way that as long as Wi-Fi is on, it's visible with the same signal-strength - no matter where I bring the computer (also far away from mobile devices).
I can connect the Mac to the SETUP node without problems...

Questions:

1. What's that Device entry?
2. What's that SETUP node? - I guess it's something running on my Mac?
3. How do I best scan the SETUP node, to learn more about it?

Comment: Device is used for things like printers. Basically, anything that is identified as not being a router, is put under there. Don't know about the rest though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's that "Device" entry?**

The entries under `Device` are [wireless ad hoc networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network), a type of wireless network that doesn't involve an access point or router, that is, a point-to-point wireless network, which usually connects two computers or a printer to a computer.

I couldn't find any Knowledge Base article at support.apple.com but theMacObserver has an [excellent article](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-create-and-use-an-ad-hoc-network-on-your-mac) about it.

**What's that SETUP node? - I guess it's something running on my Mac?**

In your case, the ad hoc network is probably a printer nearby that is broadcasting its name. Another usual ad hoc network name is [hpsetup](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00577405), the default ad hoc network used by HP printers.

**How do I best scan the SETUP node, to learn more about it?**

You could connect to it and run `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s` to get some information, but I don't think that's going to be of much use. You better go over to your neighbor's house and ask whether they have bought a printer lately.

**How can I create an ad hoc network?**

You can easily create an ad hoc network yourself:

1. In the Wi-Fi menu in the menu bar choose `Create Network...`:

   [image]
2. Choose a name (that's the name that will appear under `Device`) and press <kbd>Create</kbd>:

   [image]
3. This is the new entry:

   [image]

   If you select `Disconnect from <network>` the ad hoc network is torn down.